# How to get updated state after async call in same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this scenario which inside a function I change the state, call to async method and then want to use the updated state. the problem is that the state did not change altho is run after async call:

```
function MyComponent(){
 const [values, setValues] = useState<number[]>([]);
 const updateValue = () => {
  setValues(values.push(1));
  myAsyncMethod().then(()=>{
   console.log(values); //still empty array '[ ]' !
   setValues(values.remove(1)); //no value to remove
  });
 };
 return(
  <OtherComponent values={values} updateValue={updateValue}/>
 );
}
```

what is missing?
I don't want to use 'useRef' since i want to re render when the value change.
Is there a way so I can get the updated state after the async call?

Answer (score 1):

From your code chunk:

```
const updateValue = () => {
  setValue(2);
  myAsyncMethod().then(()=>{
   console.log(value); //still '1' !
  });
};
```

`setValue` is also asynchronous. So, that's why you are still getting the value as 1. According to your scenario, you will be getting the value to set. You can pass that rather than the state variable as:

```
const updateValue = newValue => {
  setValue(newValue);
  myAsyncMethod().then(()=>{
   console.log(newValue);
  });
};
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! But the problem is not the scoping. I want to add value to an array, update the array on the state, and then remove the value from the array when the async call is finished (I edit the question so it will be more clear). The problem is that the state in is the old one and i can't remove the value.